# Hamel base uniqueness proof

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let X be a vector space and B a Hamel base of X.
Prove that for every $x\in X$ the exist unique $x_1,...,x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $e_1,...,e_n \in B$ s.t. $x=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i e_i$

I don't know where to start.
In my first attempt i used the fact that if $B_1$ and  $B_2$ are hamel bases of X then
$cardB_1 = cardB_2$
and $spanB_1=\{ \quad\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i e_i : n\in \mathbb{N}, \quad e_1,...,e_n \in \mathbb{R}, \quad x_1,...,x_n \in B_1 \} \neq spanB_2=\{ \quad\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i k_i : n\in \mathbb{N}, \quad k_1,...,k_n \in \mathbb{R}, \quad x_1,...,x_n \in B_2 \} $

Comment: This is pretty much the definition of a Hamel basis.  What definition are you using?

Comment: If B $ \subset X$ is linearly indepented and spanB=X then is a hamel base

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- By the spanning condition, you know *some* $x_i$ exist
- If solutions in scalars $(x_i),(y_i)$ exist then $\sum_i(x_i-y_i)e_i=0$